# How can i implement threads in form submission

Tags: javascript, html, multithreading, forms, tornado

Hi all i have a "HTML" form in the front-end and Tornado in the back end My scenario is when a User clicks on submit button a function will be called in the back-end which takes quite a long time to complete so i am planning to keep a progress bar which shows whether the function execution is complete or not and  enable the user to submit another form which also uses the same function with threads BY which it means a the second form must be started but in waiting state 
How can i do this Please suggest me ...
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Before HTML5 you would not use threads but do this asychronically using callbacks. To implement this simply perform ajax requests, the callbacks can run in "parallel".

---

In order to get real parallel behavior you neef to use web workers wgich is not supported in all browsers since it is a relatively new HTML5 featute.

To read up more on web workers check out this site http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/

Comment: Thanks @Nayish is there any other way to do it with the help of tornado or anything else